# How do I make a subreport visible only on mouseover

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, subreport, telerik-reporting

I have financial report that shows monthly sales and cost numbers.  I want to place a subreport control with the detail section over the cost field and set it's visible property to 'true' only on mouse over.  The subreport will show a simple breakdown of costs.  Using Telerik controls.

Comment: What have you tried, what's not working?

Comment: I've added a subreport over the top of the cost feild, changed it's visible property to false.  I'm just not sure how to make it visible when I mouse over.

Comment: [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/html5-report-viewer-reportviewer-events-interactiveactionenter) is documentation on the InteractiveActionEnter function. That might be a good starting point to look at. [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-interactivity-how-to-add-drilldown-action) is documentation on How to Add a Drilldown Action that could be another option as well.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.